# Java to Javascript field truncated

Tags: java, javascript, json, jsp, slickgrid

I'm using slickgrid for the first time, so my design was to convert from Excel to JSON in my Servlet, and then store it as an attribute, to pass to my JSP.

In the jsp/javascript I have:

```
var data = eval ('(' + '<%=request.getAttribute("excel_data") %>' + ')');
```

The String has 22,000 rows of data in it.  It seems that after 6212 rows or so, which appears to be 1.7MB of data, and about a 622ms network response time, the connection is terminated, the variable is corrupted or whatever, and it doesn't draw my slick grid.

Does anyone know how to fix this?  Or am I limited to the number of rows I can return without doing something special?

Comment: why are you using eval?

Comment: to convert from json string to json object

Comment: Try to avoid eval, this is so dangerous... the best theory in mind is send a JSON object directly from the server side. As for the reason that you don't see the grid, is because SlickGrid works with everything or nothing, basically means get me all the data or else I'm (the grid) not doing anything!

Comment: Mmm, i used eval because I couldn't get JSON.parse() working.  But the data is coming directly from the server.  For some reason though, maybe a timeout? maybe a Java or javascript limitation?  it truncates the Java response, which is what I'm asking about.  It leaves Java as 5.8MB of data.  A third of that reaches the 'View Source' output.

Comment: The best way to debug this kind of things would be to use Firebug (a Firefox extension), from there you could see if your server did return a correct JSON object... most probably not, then if that's the case, then you could work on fixing your JSON on server side, which I wouldn't be surprised your problem is around there.